# How to get x, y, z values from Android Accelerometer sensor on a regular frequency, for instance per 20ms, 40 ms or 60 ms

Tags: android, garbage-collection, accelerometer, frequency, android-sensors

Im working on an Android project and met the situation below:

1. Now we are needing the accelerometer value on a regular frequency, such as 20ms, 40ms or 60ms
2. Now we are SENSOR_DELAY_GAME right now but we found different devices are having different intervals for this parameter. For instance, the G2 is using 40ms, G7 is using 60ms and Nexus S is using 20ms.
3. I tried to set timer or used thread.sleep but because of the GC problem of Java, they can not let the system to get the value on a regular frequency.

This is very annoying and if any one has any idea to say if inside Android SDK there is a proper method to allow me get the accelerometer values on a regular frequency, that will be very helpful!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I've done this by simply throwing away values that are sooner than I want them. Not ideal from a battery consumption standpoint as I need to have the sensors feed me more often than I need but at least then I can control that they come in on a regular interval.

Something like:

```
static final int ACCEL_SENSOR_DELAY = 100;  // the number of milisecs to wait before accepting another reading from accelerometer sensor
long lastAccelSensorChange = 0; // the last time an accelerometer reading was processed
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {


    if (sensorEvent.accuracy == SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE)  return;

    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (now-ACCEL_SENSOR_DELAY > lastAccelSensorChange) {
        lastAccelSensorChange = now;
        mCompassValues = event.values.clone();
        //... do your stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have built a code that allows you to get the exact frequency on any device.

You can download [here](http://samoht.fr/tuto/accelerometers-frequency-on-android-with-code) the project and get some explanations.

In the code, you can try the different rates. For example, the normal mode on my Galaxy S2 is 5Hz.

Answer (score 0):

Use `registerListener` by setting the sampling period as below:

```
boolean registerListener (SensorEventListener listener, Sensor sensor, int samplingPeriodUs)
```

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener%28android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor,%20int%29)

*Word of caution*: The `samplingPeriodUs` argument is only a hint to the system. Test it before using this.